# Mixing matrices within custom layer on QL 5

Tags: theater, console

I am running a school theater system, and I am trying to make a custom layer built to be user-friendly. I put a Matrix in the custom layer, and I was hoping by pressing the select button for that matrixes' channel I would be able to open it and Mix levels in that Matrix on the custom layer. Is this possible? how would I go about doing it? I am aware the top left buttons which select these matrices but I want to use the channel select button.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the SEL button to enter sends on fader mode.

You can set one of the USER KEYS to enter SENDS ON FADER mode for a specific mix or just in general though.